# Service methods firing multiple times when using new Ngrx 8 createEffect pattern

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

After switching some feature Effects over to the new `createEffct()` pattern, all of the service requests they call are now firing twice in my console output.

Here's the action:

```js
export const getSetting = createAction(
  '[Practitioner Settings] Get Setting',
  props<{ name: string }>(),
);
```

Here's an example of one such Effect using the old syntax:

```js
@Effect()
getSetting$: Observable<Action> = this.actions.pipe(
  ofType(PractitionerSettingsActionTypes.GetSetting),
  map((action: PractitionerSettingsActions.GetSetting) => action.name),
  switchMap((name: string) => {
    return this.practitionerSetingsService
               .getSetting(name)
               .pipe(
                 map(response => new PractitionerSettingsActions.GetSettingSuccess(response)),
               )
    }),
  );
```

and the new syntax, based on examples at: https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/projects/example-app/src/app/books/effects/collection.effects.ts:

```js
@Effect()
getSetting = createEffect(() =>
  this.actions.pipe(
    ofType(PractitionerSettingsActions.getSetting),
    mergeMap(({ name }) => {
      return this.practitionerSetingsService
                 .getSetting(name)
                 .pipe(
                    map(response => PractitionerSettingsActions.getSettingSuccess({ setting: response })),
                  )
      }),
    )
  );
```

I suspect it's the `mergeMap` operator that's causing this behavior since it's the only difference between the two, but I'm not sure why it would cause this, or how to access the action's payload in another way.

I have made no other changes to my application other than update the Ngrx Actions, Reducers and Effects to the v8 patterns that would cause the service calls to be executed twice.

What operator should I be using to access the action payload if not mergeMap? and if mergeMap is correct, why are my effects running more than once?

Comment: As a test can you add `this.actions.subscribe((action) => console.log(action))` somewhere? That way you can narrow down if your actions are firing off multiple times. `switchMap` only allows one inner subscription to be active at a time. It cancels any active inner subscription as soon as a new one comes in. `mergeMap` does not have this same cancelling effect. Every inner subscription will run. https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html

Comment: Let me give that a try

Comment: I added a log statement to each of my service methods. Changing `mergeMap` to `switchMap` yields the same result. I still see my log statement twice in the console for each method called by an Effect.

Comment: Just to verify, I switched to my develop branch, ran the code with the old pattern and I only see one log statement per service method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you check the example you've linked the `@Effect()` annotation is absent, and it is present in the question code. I think that is the reason it works in that way for you

Comment: Just to clarify for others. When you're using `createEffect()` you no longer need the `@Effect()` decorator

Comment: I see the same problem and we only use createEffect() without @Effect()

Comment: did you register your effects class anywhere?